# How to remove "view all posts in category..." from the_category()?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to remove that string from the title attribute of the links that `the_category()` function returns. How can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function that applies a filter to the_category output and removes the title tag

```
add_filter( 'the_category', 'remove_category_title' );
function remove_category_title( $category ) {
    return preg_replace( '/\s* title=\s*".*?"/i', '', $category );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the technique described here can be used for `the_category` as well: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201011/removing_title_attributes_from_wordpress_links/